# Oracle goes out of connection although it has enough process/session

Tags: oracle, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I have a rather high traffic Tomcat application server on a Win 2008 machine, connecting to an Oracle Database 11.2.0.1.0 (Windows Server 64x 2k8 R2; ~500-1000 unique users visit my web application in a minute). It works fine with a single Tomcat, having a maximum of 40 connections for the connection pool settiong (I'm using DBCP).

Oracle is installed on the same machine with Tomcat. When I start another Tomcat, and balance users between the two Tomcats (they are binding to different IPs and balancing is done at DNS level), one is always going out of connection with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:958)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
```

It's strange because I set both 'connections' and 'sessions' parameter to a value which is not even met when I count active sessions.

Oracle `processes` parameter is 700 `sessions` is 1216. The following query returns less than 160 sessions when one Tomcat is going out of connection:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v$session;`

Comment: Windows or UNIX/Linux?  In either case you it is likely you  running out of resources, probably virtual memory (swap space + phys. memory).  Pools are memory objects.  It doesn't matter how many are allowed if they cannot find space in memory.

Comment: It's Windows 2008 R2. It has 48GB RAM, of which only less than a half is in use. Oracle instance has 10GB private memory.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it timed out waiting to get a free connection from the pool. Doublecheck correctness of your MaxActive setting in the config of the second Tomcat.

If you had run against the limits in Oracle (MaxProcesses and MaxSessions) there would be an ORA-xxxxx error.

Comment: I think so, because there is no trace of Oracle driver in the exception stack. I even increased the maximum connections to 80, but to no avail. Not a single request is respond correctly on the second tomcat with 80 max connections.